# How to overwrite a method with a new one which uses the old?

Tags: javascript, methods

For example, I wanted to create a custom version of `CanvasRenderingContext2D.lineTo()`. The first thing I did was:

```
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.myLineTo = function(x, y) {
  this.lineTo(x + 200, y + 200);
}

ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(50, 50);
ctx.lineTo(50, 50);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();
```

and it worked. But I would prefer, if possible, to replace the `lineTo` method instead of adding `myLineTo`. The problem is that I need the first to create the second.

Unfortunately, this:

```
ctx.lineTo = function(x, y) {
  this.lineTo(x + 50, y + 50);
}
```

raises `InternalError: too much recursion`. Is there a way to copy the `lineTo` method and prevent this infinite recursion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes, here is how:

```
ctxLineTo = ctx.lineTo;
ctx.lineTo = function(x, y) {
  ctxLineTo.call(this, x + 50, y + 50);
}
```

(Be careful not to use an arrow function or else `this` will refer to the Window object.)

Comment: Pretty cool.  FYI, there's a much more flexible way to perform transforms (like a translation or scale for all subsequent calls) by manipulating the canvas's client rect